# MUSCLE Command Line Wrapper

Tags: python, command-line-interface, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to use python to complete a multiple sequence alignment. I'm using the biopython module as a base, but the command-line wrapper for biopython means that the syntax:

```
 from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline 

   muscle_exe = r"path\muscle.exe"
   in_file = r"path\Example.fasta"
   out_file = r"Path\Examplealn.fasta"
   muscle_cline = MuscleCommandLine(input=in_file, out=out_file)
   print(muscle_cline)
```

This prints the code as:

```
muscle -in Example.fasta -out Examplealn.fasta
```

however, when I run MUSCLE from command line it uses the format

```
muscle -align Example.fasta -ouput Examplealn.fasta
```

This means when I execute the python script it comes back as "invalid command line"
I have limited experience with CL so was curious if there is a way to fix this without having to somehow create a python executable script.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

BioPython is great, but if you can make it work at the command line, but not through BioPython, the simplest solution may be to just run the command-line command using Python, rather than BioPython.

There are several ways to run a command, but an easy place to start is just:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('muscle -align %s -output %s'%(input_fname,output_aname))
```

Then you can use BioPython to read in the multiple sequence alignment and manipulate it.